# Download and execute update binary from java

Tags: installation, exe, uac, auto-update

I'm pretty sure there are a lots of answers, but I can't find the right search terms...

I have client written in Java that downloads the latest update binary. After downloading, it should execute that binary (created with install4j) and terminate.

Not surprisingly, Microsoft Security Essentials detects this as a trojan and deletes the file.

I know there are other applications doing pretty much the same - how do they do it? How can I trigger e.g. UAC where the user can confirm the execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the binary I was trying to download was detected as a trojan not because my application downloaded it, but even if I rebuilt it locally - with a newer version it worked as expected.